# Friendly URL for multiple and long queries

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I tried a few different questions:

1. [php - .htaccess make URL user friendly for multiple and dynamic parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37485609/php-htaccess-make-url-user-friendly-for-multiple-and-dynamic-parameters)
2. [.htaccess for friendly URL with multiple variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451886/htaccess-for-friendly-url-with-multiple-variables)
3. [User-friendly URLs instead of Query Strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715381/user-friendly-urls-instead-of-query-strings)

The questions above were not useful, so I began to develop an alternative, but my code is returning an 404 error with multiple requests(**code1**), and with one request worked well(**code2**) So:

(**code1**) - Don´t Work - Multiple Resquest
(**code2**) - Work Fine - Single Request

**Code1**

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /~loja/index.php?a=$1&genero=$2&material=$3&cor=$4&tamanho=$5&Ordenacao=$6 [NC,L,QSA]
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /~loja/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6 [R=301,L]  
    DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Now see the Correct Code:

**Code2**

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /~loja/index.php?a=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /~loja/$1 [R=301,L]  
    DirectoryIndex index.php
```

What is wrong with (**code1**)?

Comment: @anubhava if u can help me :)

Comment: What are the URLs you're trying to rewrite? Provide a few examples please including the ones that fail.

Comment: Original URL:

site.com/index.php?a=botas-infantil&genero=feminino&material=couro&cor=marrom&tamanho=24-25&Ordenacao=MenorPreco

Comment: goal:
site.com/botas-infantil/feminino/couro/marrom/tamanho/24-25/MenorPreco

Comment: With the code 2 work´s perfect, but add more request call error 404

Comment: It works probably because that `~loja/` contains an index.php file. But when you add more segments, it gets mapped to non-existing directories, thus the 404. One more thing; if you want to rewrite that *original* url to the *goal*, where's `~loja/`? Is this the document root for `site.com`? If yes, where does your htaccess file reside?

Comment: First of all, thank you for the quick reply 
On this moment this project are on development, so working on server
http://srv98.prodns.com.br/~loja/

Comment: Later go working on http://www.ragazze.com.br
But on this Moment working on ~loja
http://srv98.prodns.com.br/~loja/

Comment: is necessary the /~loja/ on this momment becausa is the root of user´s server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first ruleset is not working because the *goal* URL contains 7 segments, but the `RewriteRule` matches 6 segments. If you add another `/([^/]*)` before the `$` in the `RewriteRule`, it'll work.

So, it'd be:

```bsh
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /~loja/index.php?a=$1&genero=$2&material=$3&cor=$4&tamanho=$5&Ordenacao=$6 [NC,L,QSA]
```

You may make a segment/character optional by appending a `?` character at the end of it.

The second part of the first ruleset is completely wrong and serves no purpose. First, you should note that `THE_REQUEST` variable contains the full HTTP request line as the [documentation states](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

> `THE_REQUEST` contains the full HTTP request line sent by the browser to the server (e.g., `GET /index.html HTTP/1.1`). This does not include any additional headers sent by the browser. This value has not been unescaped (decoded), unlike most other variables below.

You don't want to use that, use `REQUEST_URI` instead.

#### The 404

The reason you're getting that 404 error, is that because the `RewriteRule` fails to match the request URI, the URL does not get rewritten to index.php. That directory hierarchy does not exist on the filesystem, thus the 404.

#### Optional URI segments

Your original ruleset was expecting exact count of URI arguments. If you need to be more flexible about this, you can try this ruleset which accepts 1-7 segments and map them to query strings:

```bsh
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php
    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)$ /~loja/index.php?a=$1&genero=$2&material=$3&cor=$4&tamanho=$5&Ordenacao=$6 [NC,L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

When you test this, note the empty query strings. On the PHP side of things, you need to use `empty()` instead of `isset()`, to see if the querystring exists. As they're always set, but empty.

#### Excluding `admin/`

In order to exclude this rules to be applied on the `admin/` path, you can update the above `RewriteCond` like this:

```bsh
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(index\.php|admin)
```

Comment: i tried with THE_REQUEST Begin working :D
with REQUEST_URI make error.

now i´ll make root my archives url (js, css)
i like to know if exist an way to work with 1 request too? or 2?
i tried with 7 requests working well!

http://srv98.prodns.com.br/~loja/botas-infantil/feminino/couro/marrom/tamanho/24-25/MenorPreco

Comment: Yes, it's possible to make it work with less URI segments as well. Will update the answer ASAP.

Comment: i try any modification for any conflicts to ~loja/admin/*

  
#RewriteRule ^admin$ - [PT]
RewriteRule ^admin/.$ - [PT]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/admin

Comment: I'd like to say that your code is unrepeatable.
Perfect!
I could not do it alone.
It's working very well.
I only have to thank you for your vast knowledge.
Thanks to people like you that the world gets better and better.
Thank you so much!!!